# Reliable way to connect to Amazon RDS endpoint

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Currently we connect from our app to the RDS endpoint using it's hostname:

xxxx-db.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com

It seems the dns service went down for a period of time last night resulting in:

```
ERROR - 2019-07-11 23:02:46 --> Severity: Warning --> mysqli::real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution /var/app/current/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php 201
ERROR - 2019-07-11 23:02:46 --> Severity: Warning --> mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution /var/app/current/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php 201
ERROR - 2019-07-11 23:02:46 --> Unable to connect to the database
```

Is there a better way to access the DB server skipping the dns?

Comment: It would seem unlikely that the AWS DNS service would fail like that. It could be caused by the chain of DNS servers used to reach the Top-level domain. Did you try `dig` or `nslookup` to try and diagnose the situation?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein No because it happened for around 10 minutes during the night.